# Battery discharges while computer is off

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, battery

I bought a hp 15-r003np 2 weeks ago and installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS with dual boot (to windows 8). When i shutdown ubuntu, in the next day battery has 85% of charge, despite the computer shutdown. If i power off in windows battery charge is 100% in the next day. Does anyone have noticed the same problem? I think the network adapter is not on wol mode, seen via windows network config properties. I need help to solve this problem... (it's not right to work around restarting to windows to do the shutdown properly...)

Comment: I too have the same problem. I hope someone will answer this soon.